# Joomla: How to assign custom layout to category?

Tags: templates, joomla

I have a magazine using Joomla. I need to be able to have different layouts for different issues.

I copied the default template, modified it and it shows just fine in Template manager, but how do I actually assign it to a category so all articles added to that category would automatically use it?

UPDATE: Solution below seems to work... however now it seems to open it correctly only when I go through the blog view and when I use my link on the front page directly to an article it uses wrong layout?

Comment: Which version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Joomla 1.6 or 1.7, you should be able to assign a template to a menu item. So if you have a menu item pointing to the blog view of a category. Set the corresponding template to that menu item.
This is done in Extensions -> Template Manager -> Styles -> "Your Magazine Template"

Comment: So by adding menu item to the category (magazine issue) the template will automatically also assign to all sub-categories?